# Laravel - Check checkbox if json value saved in database

Tags: html, laravel, checkbox

I have database records that are saved in json. In edit form I want those check boxes checked if, the values are saved in database.

**Database Value**

```
| ID |           items            |
|----|----------------------------|
|  1 | ["cars","bikes","planes"] |
|  2 | ["fruits", "vegetables"]   |
```

**Form**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="cars">
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="planes">
```

**Controller**

```
 $items= Items::pluck('items');
 return view('edit', compact('items'));
```

**I tried**

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="cars" {{ json_decode($items),"cars" ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

**and**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="cars" {{ $items == "cars" ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: Add the items json to your question please.

Comment: Oh sorry I saw it above

Comment: and by the way its array, not json, json is in key value pair

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$items= json_decode(Items::pluck('items'));
```

And then you can use `in_array()` method to find the exact match item you want to check.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="cars" {{ in_array('cars',$items) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: It throws ``unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 43 bytes``

Comment: can you show me what does this return $items= Items::pluck('items');

Comment: ``0 "[\"cars\",\"bikes\"]" ``

Comment: use the json_decode to parse the string, And then in_array method will check for the specific value in the array

Comment: ``in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given``

Comment: can you dd the items, what does it gives

Comment: ``array:1 [▼
  0 => "["cars","bikes"]"
]``

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fetch all items first

```
$items= Items::select('items')->get();
```

then merged all columns contains items

```
$new_items = [] 

$items.map(function($item){
array_merge($new_items,item)  
}
```

should be resulted here on 1 array

```
$new_items  = ["cars","bikes","planes","fruits", "vegetables"]
```

then you can use Haider Ali answer on frontend

```
return view('edit', compact('new_items'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

```
<?php $items = json_decode($items); ?>


<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="cars" {{ array_has($items, "cars") ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: Not worked.
Only this works. I know it's not efficient.
``<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" @foreach($items as $item)
      @foreach(json_decode($item) as $itm) {{ $itm == "cars" ? "checked" : "" }} @endforeach @endforeach> Cars``
for each item.

Comment: what is in $item variable ?

Comment: ``$item`` is used for ``foreach`` parameter. ``$items`` is collection of array in database